# Background Check on Prospective Hires

Tags: team-management, planning, process

I'm looking to start up a small business, and I'd like to know if anybody here--and I'm not sure if this question belongs here--might know of a method to ascertain the following things in a cost-effective manner for which the applicant has authorized:

1: Criminal Record

2: Previous Job History

3: Driving Record

4: University Attendance

5: University Transcripts

Comment: Note to moderators: "software recommendations" should be shortened to just "recommendations" to cover this specific use case.

Comment: For the OP: This question might fit elsewhere on the SE network, but I don't think so. It's what we call a "shopping" question, which is a request for a specific software, tool, or service recommendation. You might check out Workplace SE, but I'm pretty sure it will be off-topic there, too. Still, welcome to PMSE; I hope you'll find other topics that receive a warmer reception.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about conducting background screens, which is not about the field of project management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one has responded, so I'll give some input. This is the perspective of an informed employee/contractor.

1. There are companies that do this. With basic info from an application(Name, DOB, SS/GovID #, and Driver's License #) you should be able to get a criminal history fairly cheaply.
2. A prospective employee should give you a job history +  references. You can get this verified by calling references or sending an email. References are often checked by e-mail surveys now.
3. See 1. This may be public record.

4 and 5. Ask for a transcript. If the student requests it, universities will either send you an official one directly. You may also ask for an unofficial transcript which can be printed from a schools website.

I've been told that a background check in the USA runs around $35USD, per head. Perhaps, to save time and costs, run checks after you have verified university enrollment and job history. This way, you've filtered out unlikely candidates.

Also, consider that any company you may go with might have a bulk rate for background checks. The same may go for drug tests if that is an objective as well.